# Toggle isn't executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click function, which is being executed, because the fadeToggles work. But the div#overlay-sources I'm trying to animate, isn't animated. I have set it a height of 0px to start with, and then it should be animated to 480px. The animation in itself works, I have tested it outside of the toggle function. But somehow the toggle function isn't executed.

```
$("#button-up").click(function(){
    $("#overlay-sources").toggle(
        function()
        {
          $(this).animate({height: "480px"}, 500);
        },
        function()
        {
          $(this).animate({height: "0px"}, 500);
        });

    $("#overlay-sources").fadeToggle('fast');
    $("#blackout").fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed.

```
$("#button-up").toggle(
    function()
    {
        $("#overlay-sources").animate({top: "141px"}, 500);
        $("#blackout").fadeToggle('fast');
    },
    function()
    {
        $("#overlay-sources").animate({top: "690px"}, 500);
        $("#blackout").fadeToggle('fast');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to jQueryUI, or have already included it, that entire top part:

```
$("#overlay-sources").toggle(
        function()
        {
          $(this).animate({height: "480px"}, 500);
        },
        function()
        {
          $(this).animate({height: "0px"}, 500);
        });
```

Becomes:

`$("#overlay-sources").slideToggle(500);`

But don't CSS the height to 0, simply `display:none`, and the function will handle the height animation.

**EDIT**

I'm sorry, I was mistaken. It looks like `slideToggle` is a part of the jQuery core library, and does not require jQuery UI

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way you can make it slide down instead of up?

Comment: In what respect? By default, it slides down to reveal and up to conceal

Comment: Yes, I need it the other way around, so slide down to conceal, up to reveal.